# How to implement Excel-like Conditional formatting and “color scale” in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services

I have a table like below in SSRS

```
 category 2018 percentage 2019 percentage
  c1      55    17%       7     11%      
  c2      0      0%       20     25%
  c3      6      2%       1      1%
  c4      26     8%       5     11%
  c5      4      1%       2      4%
  c6      10     3%       6      8%
```

I want implement excel like Conditional formatting with color scales in SSRS report and want to fill(background color) for top 3 numbers in 2018 column and 2019 column . The sorting order should remain on category.
That means, i need to fill back ground color for 55,26 and 10 under 2018 and 20,6 and 7 in 2019 columns.
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your data is like what is in the CTE you can use a rank function partition by year and ordered by the actual value to figure out what the rankings for each year is (like you mentioned.. top 3 for the year).

Then based on the ranking figure.. assign a color to it and then use that color value as your background color

sample code:

```
  ;with mycte as (

  select
  'c1' as category ,55 as cat_value,'17%' as cat_percentage,2018 as cat_year
  union all
    select
  'c2',0,'0%',2018
  union all
    select
  'c3',6,'2%',2018
  union all
    select
  'c4',26,'8%',2018
  union all
    select
  'c5',4,'1%',2018
  union all
    select
  'c6',10,'3%',2018
  union all
    select
  'c1',7,'11%',2019
  union all
    select
  'c2',20,'25%',2019
  union all
    select
  'c3',1,'1%',2019
  union all
    select
  'c4',5,'11%',2019
  union all
    select
  'c5',2,'4%',2019
  union all
    select
  'c6',6,'8%',2019
 )
 ,rankings as (
 select 
 mycte.*

 ,RANK() over (partition by cat_year order by cat_value desc) as rank_value

 from mycte
 )

 Select *
 ,case when rank_value = 1 then 'Red'
 when rank_value = 2 then 'Blue'
 when rank_value = 3 then 'Green'
 else 'white' end as back_color
 from rankings
```

then in your report, select the cell that has the value you want colored .. set the background color of that cell to:

```
=fields!back_color.value
```

Comment: Thanks Haryy  for the response, but i cannot combine the year column as it will change the report format . Can we add the color column with out changing the format?

Comment: I have added extra column to the CTE  and could achive i needed. Thanks a lot . your response helped

Comment: If it has answered your questions.. please accept my answer